# SSRS reporting, add multiple table with different Dataset in a list

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have 2 datasets, each of them has a related column.

Query Result of First Dataset (dsUser)

```
RefCol    Name    Date
1         JF      2014-01-01
2         Rene    2014-02-01
...
```

Query Result of the second DataSet (dsPermission)

```
RefCol  Name      Permission           Note
1       JF        Create User          To create a user
1       JF        Modify User
2       Rene      Test
2       Rene      Permision 2
```

I would like to have a list of the first dataset, and a table of the second dataset.
As you can see, I have a RefCol which I will group by on it.

I would like to avoid using sub report.

The desired ouput would be:

```
Name : JF
Date : 2014-01-01

Permission List Table
**Permission**           **Note**
Create User          To create a user
Modify User
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Name : Rene
Date : 2014-02-01

Permission List Table
**Permission**           **Note**
Test          
Permision 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can have two Data regions in one report, but not a data region inside another data region.

When you say you want a List and a Table thats fine you can do this, You can have a List pointing to One of your Data Sets and another Table Region pointing to other data set.

But when you say you want to Group by these two with each other this is something not possible in SSRS.

You will have to stick to one data region and that Data region will point back to Only one Data set. If you want data from both Data sets, you will need to create another data set which will combine queries from other both data sets and pull the data together in one data set. As in SSRS any one Data region can only point back to only one data set.

Comment: Ok,I understand. The only thing I can do for this issue is using SubReport.

Comment: If you have to have it in List and Table data regions then yes Sub-Report is the only option, But if you can have it all in one tabular report you can use the drill through functionality which is really cool.

Comment: Thanks a lot M.Ali . What I posted is a simple example of what I'am trying to do. In reallity, I have 12 tables to manage for each groups (RefCol) . It would be really hard join every query to create a single dataset. It is really hard to beleive that SSRS didn't think about this kind of situation. Sub Report technique is fine but not optimized.

Comment: 12 tables hmmm not really a big deal :) but anyway what ever suits you best atleast I have narrowed down your option to real practical ones. If this answer helped you please accept it thank you.